# copying values of a column to another one whenever it is not NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying copy all element of V1 to column Tot whenever it is not NA.

```
     pre.passenger[,"Tot"] = ifelse(is.na(pre.passenger[,"V1"]),pre.passenger[,"Tot"],pre.passenger[,"V1"])



    structure(list(mode.passenger = structure(list(V1 = c(NA, 3, 
3, NA, 3, 3)), row.names = c("NA.113", "171", "299", "NA.114", 
"1", "145"), class = "data.frame"), Tot = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 30L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

it gives me this output:

```
   V1 Tot
8  NA   1
9   3   1
10  3   1
11 NA   1
30  3   1
31  3   1
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `str` of data, it looks like you have a nested dataframe.

```
str(df)

#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ mode.passenger:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ V1: num  NA 3 3 NA 3 3
# $ Tot           : int  1 NA NA 1 1 1
```

You could do

```
inds <- !is.na(df$mode.passenger$V1)
df$Tot[inds] <- df$mode.passenger$V1[inds]

df
#   V1 Tot
#8  NA   1
#9   3   3
#10  3   3
#11 NA   1
#30  3   3
#31  3   3
```

Comment: I am trying to post a question, in dput function for one of the variable Lable=c(  is very large for 4 rows and 4 column. do you know what is problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: @hghg Do you have a nested dataframe again? Check `str(df)`.

Comment: 'data.frame': 1049 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ SAMPN  : Factor w/ 3724 levels "    4","    8",..: 4 4 4 17 28 28 28 30 41 41 ...
 $ id     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ overlap: chr  "3" NA "1" NA ...
 $ PERNO  : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...

Comment: yeah...I guess that is because you have too many levels in your data. Convert it to character and it should help.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the column to a regular data.frame column and then do the change

```
pre.passenger <-  do.call(data.frame, pre.passenger)
row.names(pre.passenger) <- NULL
pre.passenger[,"Tot"] <- ifelse(is.na(pre.passenger[,"V1"]),pre.passenger[,"Tot"],
                        pre.passenger[,"V1"])
#  V1 Tot
#1 NA   1
#2  3   3
#3  3   3
#4 NA   1
#5  3   3
#6  3   3
```